# Compare R-squared across samples

Tags: predictive-models, r-squared

I estimate the same OLS model (same outcome and explanatory variables) on two different samples. I want to determine if the proportion of the variance explained in sample 1 is significantly larger than that in sample 2. I thought I could just compare the R-squared of the models estimated on the two samples. But a professor of statistics told me that we cannot compare R-squared across samples. Now I am at a loss.

Note that:

1. I am not interested in whether the coefficients differ across samples (which can be tested using the Chow test). I am interested in the **difference in the predictability of the outcome variable given the explanatory variables** between the two samples.
2. The distributions of the outcome and the explanatory variables differ a lot between the two samples.